# Azure B2C Application Roles (Graph api)

Tags: asp.net, api, azure, graph, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to get the Roles associated only with some specific application ID, using Azure/MS Graph api?
Note: I'm trying to get that from a asp.net web api.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Microsoft Graph API's beta endpoint doesn't currently allow you to list AppRoleAssignments. Fortunately, the Azure AD Graph API does work for this (plus, it's not a beta endpoint, so it's more likely to be stable).

To list all app roles a user is assigned:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

To list all app roles a group is assigned:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/groups/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

To do the reverse, and list all users or groups assigned to an app:

```
   https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRolesAssignedTo?api-version=1.6
```

**Alternative option**: In the new Azure portal, under "Enterprise applications" > (your app) > "Users and groups", you'll see the list of users who are assigned to the application, as well as the app role they are assigned to. After testing, you could do the equivalent thing using a Microsoft Graph API request :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/d0790296-0a14-4ab1-8f6c-4e4d3eb03036/appRoleAssignments
```

Your could get the service principal under "Enterprise applications" > (your app) > Properties> Object ID